# croppic plugin in laravel 5.3 throws json error cant figure out the answer need

Tags: laravel-5, croppic

I am using croppic plugin for the first time but it throws an error while uploading photo. I don't understand what i have done wrong. I have attached an image regarding it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an unexpected token error, it means somewhere in your code you didn't terminate a line or a block of code.

The parser is running into an "<" character and doesn't know what to do with it.